# Centering only a part of a presentation

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have the following code

```
\begin{itemize} 
         \item Optimal Effort:\\
         $DPV{\Pi}_1(e)=-\psi(e)+(I+pe)\delta \longrightarrow \overline{e}=p\delta$ \\[0.2cm]
          \item Participation Decision:\\
           $DPV{\Pi}_0(e)=-\psi(e)\delta +(I+pe)\delta^2$ $\longrightarrow e_0=\argmax_e{DPV{\Pi}_0(e)}\\
          \centering $\downarrow$\\

          $DPV{\Pi}_0(e_0)\geq A\delta^2$ \\
          {\centering $\downarrow$\\
          $p\geq\phi_E$} \\[0.2cm]

         \item jkgjhghg
        \end{itemize}
```

The problem is that the second item is also in the center, but I want to be on the left side, bellow the first item

Comment: Please provide complete minimal working example started with ``\documentclass{....} \usepackage{..} \begin{document} ...\end{document``. Also add your definitions of math function.  I guess, that centering of last item arise since you request it with ``\centering`` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{empheq}%,amssymb

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
\item Optimal Effort:
    \[  DPV{\Pi}_1(e) = -\psi(e)+(I+pe)\delta 
                \longrightarrow \overline{e}=p\delta    
    \]
\item Participation Decision:
    \begin{gather*}
DPV{\Pi}_0(e) = -\psi(e)\delta +(I+pe)\delta^2
    \longrightarrow e_0=\arg\max_e\{DPV{\Pi}_0(e)\} \\
            \downarrow                              \\
DPV{\Pi}_0(e_0)\geq A\delta^2                       \\
            \downarrow                              \\
p\geq\phi_E
    \end{gather*}
\item   jkgjhghg
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

I improvised your math. I suspect, that the problems of centering is caused with `centering` command, which you use twice in your (not)MWE. I put your equations in displaymath environment `\[ ... \]` and `\begin{gather*} .... \end{gather*}`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! This is exactly what I was looking for!!!

Comment: @Yorgos Perhaps you would like to consider accepting the answer in that case?